# Is there a way to make sure MongoDB always arranges objects in an an array in a particular order?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using MongoDB via mongoose.Is there a way to make sure MongoDB always arranges objects in an an array in a particular order?

Consider the schema code below:

```
{
    _id: '1234',
    arrayOfObjects:[{
        data:'some data'
        createdAt:'some date'      
    }]
}
```

I want to create a materialized view so the objects might be inserted in a random order and not in the order of their creation dates. Is there a way to make sure MongoDB always arranges objects in an an array in a particular order? Or do I have to do this when I query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use $sort operator: [read more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/)

a quick example:

schema sample:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "arrayField": [
    { "id" : 1, "someNumber" : 6 },
    { "id" : 2, "someNumber" : 9 }
  ]
}
```

Query sample; Sorting the `arrayField` by `someNumber` in ascending order would be like:

```
update.(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
       arrayField: {
         $each: [ { id: 3, someNumber: 8 }, { id: 4, someNumber: 7 }, { id: 5, someNumber: 6 } ],
         $sort: { someNumber: 1 }
       }
     }
   }
)
```